# ActionScript-3 Call Function on Every Frame Without Having to KeyFrame every Frame in between

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe

I want to call a function once per frame between keyframe 1 and keyframe 60, but i don't want to have to create a keyframe on EVERY single frame in between with an action calling the function. is there a simple way like tweening, to make this function execute once on every frame without having to make 60 unique keyframes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep a count variable and use the `ENTER_FRAME` event. Something like:

```
// create a count var somewhere in your class or whatever
private var m_currCount:int = 0;

// add an EnterFrame event listener to the stage
this.stage.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, this._onUpdate );

// our update function
private function _onUpdate( e:Event ):void
{
    // call your function here
    this.doSomething();

    // up our count
    this.m_currCount++;

    // if it's 60, then stop
    if( this.m_currCount >= 60 )
        this.stage.removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, this._onUpdate );
}
```

Comment: If you're in a MovieClip, you can use currentFrame to check the frame number. Might be better than the counter, in some situations.